# scrollIntoView function doesn't scroll anywhere

Tags: javascript, php, html, js-scrollintoview

I can't figure out why, but `scrollIntoView()` function doesn't work in Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 and I believe in any other either. The browser displays no errors and screen isn't scrolling anywhere. I haven't been able to find any answer in the Internet. Below is simplified code:

```
// [...]
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        if (is_array($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $element) { ?>
                <tr data-someid="<?= $element->some_id ?>">
                    <th><?= $element->id ?></th>
                    <td><?= $element->name ?></td>
                    <td><?= $element->surname ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } 
        } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
// [...]
<script>
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var someId = url.searchParams.get('some_id');
    var element= document.querySelector('[data-someid="' + someId + '"]');
    console.log(element); // displays the element well
    element.scrollIntoView();
</script>
// [...]
```

Do somebody have any ideas why it doesn't work?

P.S. I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net) to render the table and for convenience didn't display it in the code.

Comment: Where did you define `someId`?

Comment: @KHansen Oh, sorry. I just have updated the question. Please, look at it. It is gotten from uri parameters